# Error:Can't conver string to integer while running app in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Showing app/views/student/edit.erb where **line #156** raised:

```
can't convert String into Integer
```

Extracted source (around line #156):

```
154:<div class="label-field-pair">
155:<label for="student_country"><%= t('select_native') %></label>
156:<div class="text-input-bg_form"> <%= select :student,  :select_native, [["Arab","arab"]["Non Arab","non_arab" ]],  { :prompt => "#{t('select_native')}" } %> </div>
157:</div>
158: 
159:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma is missing in array, add comma and it will work.

```
[["Arab","arab"],["Non Arab","non_arab" ]] 
<%= select :student,  :select_native, [["Arab","arab"], ["Non Arab","non_arab" ]],  { :prompt => "#{t('select_native')}" } %>
```